# static big files and a way to serve them securely (central authentication CDN)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, cdn, http-authentication

I need to serve few static big files(about 4GB each) to several users, using 5 servers that are in different geographical regions.

The idea is that nobody else gets the content as there's information in those files that is not meant for general public.

The task is to serve those files using a web server and some authentication mechanism or rewrite URLs or something that expires in a timely manner.

For this I could do a web app that would serve the clients the links and/or the credentials needed to access the files.

I have seen, for instance, that nginx could check if a cookie is set in the browser and could do a URL rewrite based on this fact but this might not be enough as I can't seem to find a way to validate the cookie contents.

I also saw the nginx http_auth works for authentication on a reverse proxy for emails. This might be a good idea, but again, static big files and a way to serve them securely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using s3 form amazon. it`s easy to use, secure and serves your requests.